# How to open text file on the screen of Linux (raspberry pi 4)

Tags: python-3.x, linux, raspberry-pi, popen

I try to open the text file on the linux os screen using python 3  but keep receive permission denied.

How could i open the text file using python3 on linux os (raspberry pi os ) and view file as   full screen ?

Note: I try both popen and os.system both being permission denied.

Here is my code :

```
import os
from subprocess import Popen            
            
file_name = 'logfile_month_1_year_2023.txt'
file_path = '/home/csiro/Desktop/final_dobot_package/pydobot/logfile/'
file_open = os.path.join (file_path , file_name)
#os.system(r"/home/csiro/Desktop/final_dobot_package/pydobot/logfile/" + file)
Popen(file_open)
```

Answer (score 0):

Permission denied could be a permission issue of the file that you are trying to open. Try hitting `ls -l` in the linux terminal first to see whether the particular user that you are using has read access.